# Describe topology space X(meaning topology induced by R usual topology)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Here is given set $X$ and it's split.

$(-\infty,0]=(-\infty;-1) \cup$ {$-1$} $\cup (-1,0)\cup$ {$0$}.

a)Describe topology space $X$(meaning topology induced by $R$ usual topology)

b)Describe $X$ factor space.

c)Check if $X$ factor space is hausdorff space.

My work.

For a)open sets in $X$ we will get by intersection of open sets in usual topology and $X$.

So open sets are $(\alpha,0],(\alpha,b)$ $\alpha,b\in R$ and union of this sets.

which will be topology base for $X$.

b)let $f(x)=\alpha$  $x\in (-\infty;-1)$, $f(-1)=b$, $f(y)=\gamma$, $y\in(-1,0)$, $f(0)=a$

So $Y=(\alpha,b,\gamma,a)$ and $f:X\to Y$ surjective function.By definition of factor topology open sets in $Y$ are sets whose inverse maps are open in $X$.

So for saving some time I will not write all inverse maps

open sets are ($\alpha,\gamma $ ,{$\alpha,b$},{$\alpha,\gamma$},{$b,\gamma$,},{$\alpha,b,\gamma$},$\emptyset$)

(for example by {$\alpha,b$} we mean $(\infty,-1]$)

c)A topological space X is Hausdorff if for any $x, y ∈ X$ with $x \neq y$ there
exist open sets $U$ containing $x$ and $V$ containing $y$ such that $U\cap V$ = ∅

let $x\in U$ $y \in V$ s.t. $U\cap V=\emptyset$

And I can't continue from here can you help?

For $a),b)$
my work is correct?

Comment: What is $\sim$?

Comment: @Jakobian Thank you I edited.

Comment: All open neighbourhoods of $b$ contain $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotient space has $4$ points (as $X$ is split into $4$ sets).

From left to right I'll call these $Y=\{\alpha, \beta,\gamma,\delta\}$, say.

It's clear that $\{\beta\}$ and $\{\delta\}$ are closed singleton sets and $\{\alpha\}$ and $\{\gamma\}$ are open singletons (isolated points) and $\{\gamma, \delta\}$ is open too as $(-1,0]$ is open in $X$. Also $\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma\}$ is open, as their union in $X$ is $(-\infty,0)$, which is open in $\Bbb R$ and $X$ too.

A topology on a finite set $Y$ is easiest to describe by the minimal base : for each point $y \in Y$ we need to give the smallest open set $O_y$ that contains $y$. All open sets are just unions of these (plus $\emptyset$ of course).

Here

- $O_\alpha = \{\alpha\}$
- $O_\beta = \{\alpha, \beta, \gamma\}$
- $O_\gamma = \{\gamma\}$
- $O_\delta = \{\gamma, \delta\}$.

A finite space $Y$ is Hausdorff iff $O_y=\{y\}$ for all $y$ iff it's discrete. So this is *not* the case here.

Comment: Can you please say what you mean saying it's discrete?

Comment: Ah you mean discrete topology?

Comment: @unit1991 Yes, on a finite set there is only **one** Hausdorff topology, the discrete topology.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what you mean $O_y=\{y\}$ for all $y$ is discrete?

Comment: Can't we simply say that $\beta$   $\in Y$  therefore if it is discrete topology it must be open but it isn't so we get contradiction.

Comment: No, $O_\beta=\{\alpha, \beta,\gamma\}$ means that any open set that contains $\beta$ *always* also contains $\alpha$ and $\gamma$, so $Y$ is not discrete and we cannot find disjoint open neighbourhoods of $\alpha$  and $\beta$ e.g. @unit1991

Comment: Sorry for asking many questions but last question.How you concluded that $Y$ is not discrete?

Comment: @unit1991 Not **all** subsets of $Y$ are open. E.g. $\{\beta\}$ is not.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question.You said all open sets are union of those.But for example {$\alpha,\beta$} is also open how you represent this with union?

Comment: $\{\alpha, \beta\}$ is not open, as its inverse image $(-\infty,-1]$ is not open in $X$.

Comment: If we had $(a,b]$ open in $X$ instead of $(a,b)$ then $(-\infty,-1]$ would be open yes?

Comment: @unit1991 Yes, but we inherit the usual topology of $\Bbb R$;  there is no choice.